# Replace spaces in files within subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash

I have about 10,000 directories containing files. I want to write a loop that iterates through each directory, picks out a .`txt` file, and replaces any spaces with a `_`. How can I do this?

```
for f in *FOLDERS*
do
    cd "$f" && echo "Entering into $f" || { echo "Error: could not enter into $f"; continue; }
    for y in $(ls *.txt | mv "$y" "${y// /_}")
    do
        echo ${y}
    done
done
```

But it doesn't work for each directory. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You want to replace spaces by `_` in file _names only_ or in directory names too? `I have about 10,000 directories` Have you considered using python?

Comment: Don't use Python to perform shell functions. Manipulating file name is more concisely and more easily done by shell code. The equivalent Python code is enormously more complex.

Comment: You should check your code with shellcheck.net. You have some buggy behaviors to watch out for (0) you should never process the output of `ls` as input for anything other than human eyeballs, (1) you cannot pipe to `mv` and have it do anything sensible, (2) you should not use an unquoted subshell as input for a `for in` construct, especially not if you expect it to print filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in */; do
    cd "$d" || exit
    for t in *\ *.txt; do
        [[ -f $t ]] && mv -i "$t" "${t// /_}"
    done
    cd ..
done
```

Or, if you want to do it recursively (for all subdirectories in any depth):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

for d in **/; do
    cd "$d" || exit
    for t in *\ *.txt; do
        [[ -f $t ]] && mv -i "$t" "${t// /_}"
    done
    cd - >/dev/null
done
```

Comment: @Jetchisel Perhaps, in order to get rid of `cd -` or `cd ..`.

Answer (score 3):

1. List all files with spaces in filenames.
2. In that list, duplicate each line. In the second line, change all spaces in the filename for `_`.
3. For every two lines, execute `mv`.

```
find *FOLDERS* -type f -name '* *.txt' -print0 |
# Duplicate the line. Replace spaces by _ in the second line.
sed -Ez 'h ; s@.*/@@ ; s@ @_@g ; G ; s@([^\x00]*)\x00(.*/)?([^/]*)@\2\3\x00\2\1@' |
# Execute mv for each two arguments.
xargs -0 -n2 echo mv -v
```

Answer (score 3):

Select files with `find`, then run `bash` to perform the filename manipulation.

```
find . -type f -name '* *.txt' -exec bash -c 'for path; do
    basename="${path##*/}"
    dir="${path%/*}"
    echo mv "$path" "$dir"/"${basename// /_}"
done'  - {} +
```

This is fully recursive; if you don't want that you can limit the selection depth with `find`. The other advantage to using `find` is you can tell for sure what files you will be operating on before you run the dangerous part.

The above is harmless as-is, to make it actually perform its function remove the `echo`  before the `mv`.

Answer (score 1):

This is why your script is not working. Consider this folder structure:

```
$ ls
d1  d2  d3
```

Now lets try to `cd` into each folder:

```
$ for d in *; { cd $d; pwd; }
/tmp/d1
bash: cd: d2: No such file or directory
/tmp/d1
bash: cd: d3: No such file or directory
/tmp/d1
```

You have to go back to 'home' folder first:

```
$ for d in *; { cd $d; pwd; cd ..; }
/tmp/d1
/tmp/d2
/tmp/d3
```

Or use full path in `$d` definition:

```
$ for d in $PWD/*; { cd $d; pwd; }
/tmp/d1
/tmp/d2
/tmp/d3
```

Answer (score 1):

For something fast, you will probably want Sorpigal's answer; this will still work, but it's slower.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

find . -type f -name '* *.txt' > stack

next () {
[[ -s stack ]] && main
end
}

main () { 
line=$(sed -n "1p" stack)
echo "${line}" | tr '/' '\n' > f2
basename=$(sed -n "$p" f2)
sed -i "$d" f2
dirname=$(cat f2 | tr '\n' '/')
newname=$(echo "${basename}" | tr ' ' '_')
mv -v "${dirname}/${basename}" "${dirname}/${newname}"
sed -i "1d" stack
rm -v ./f2
next
}

end () {
rm -v ./stack
exit 0
}

next
```